# Being accused of interview fraud after working 2 years

Tags: work-environment, united-kingdom

I interviewed with a software company 2 years ago.

I completed a time constrained online judge programming task, and did well but not 100%. After accepting an offer, I successfully completed a 6 months probation period.

Fast forward 2 years, and a task goes over the estimated time and I am being threatened with being let go and accused with interview fraud. I don't really know to deal with the situation.

Can anyone offer advice?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66871/discussion-on-question-by-lamaocam-being-accused-of-interview-fraud-after-workin).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

### It's time to dust off the ole resume/cv

At this point, if you are being threatened ( to be fired ), **it's time to update your resume/CV** and start looking immediately.  If your employer has already moved to threatening your job after over 2 years of service, why would you want to wait and hope for this event to pass?

Also keep in mind that in my experience, *it is always easier to find a job when you are currently employed*.  In other words *do not wait* to be fired to begin your job search.

I do not know whether or not you falsified information during the interview process or not, but **always be honest in your relations with employers** in regards to your capabilities and accomplishments.

Comment: I totally agree with finding a new job but how can this happen in a first world country at a publicly listed company and have them get away scott free. Is there nothing protecting the employee in such situations? Mind you these were verbal threaths not written warnings.

Comment: @Lamaocam Most of the time, at least here in the US, there is little protection afforded to the employee.  Other countries offer some level of protection.  Regardless if they want you gone, eventually you will be gone.

Comment: @Lamaocam While in the UK I'm fairly sure that you have *a little more *protection than in the US, the core idea is the same: your company isn't interested in finding the real issue, they'd rather blame you and even accuse you of fraud after having proven your skills for 2 years. This is not a company you want to work for, so time to find a new job.

Comment: @Lamaocam because bad, insecure managers exist all over the world and the kind that push unrealistic deadlines are often very good at talking themselves up to their superiors.

Comment: @Lamaocam Verbal threats? How many were there and by whom?

Comment: @Lamaocam Being a publicly listed company in a first world country means they likely have a lot of money to spend on top lawyers to defend against wrongful termination lawsuits.  If you do get fired, you might consider talking to a lawyer but just make sure the potential juice is worth the squeeze.  Big companies get away with things way worse than this.

Answer (score 41):

Consult a lawyer.

No one here can offer you legal advice.

Two years is a bit long to come up with that, so there's clearly something else at play here.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible they want to get rid of you, and they are looking for a way to get you fired. It seems that they take this small mistake that you made and try to blow it out of proportion.

Consult a lawyer before taking any actions, and document everything you do (from now on).

Comment: This doesn't really add anything not presented by the other two answers...

Comment: "It is possible"? I am unable to come up with any plausible explanation.  "You are doing great work.  We are depending on you for the big project.  Your leadership is taking us to the next level.  We reviewed your interview assessment task from two years ago and decided you may have been cheating." does not compute.

Comment: It is not a mistake by default, and what I was trying to explain is that this minor mistake is turned into something worse by including the cheating on the task two years ago.

Anyway, this is how I interpreted the question. I could be wrong offcourse

Answer (score 0):

You could contact [ACAS](http://www.acas.org.uk), they'll be able to offer you advice about your situation and what to do next.
I am not a lawyer, but have been in a similar situation, and being threatened to "be let go" could be "constructive dismissal"

Ultimately, like many others here have said, is this somewhere you want to continue working?

Answer (score -1):

## Ask for an apology

The feasibility of this of course depends on the circumstances, but strange as it may sound, the only way to make the working situation less toxic is if you display strength and state that you expect an apology.

Perhaps the person who accused you was just in a (really) bad mood at the moment because the task did not get completed, and though this is no excuse to start threatening his underlings, it did happen and *you may consider to forgive him for that*.

---

Bottom line is: regardless of what happened 2 years ago, if the situation stays such that everyone feels that you may need to apologize then it will only keep getting worse for you. In that case it is indeed best to start packing as the existing answers suggest.

Comment: Your answer is to ask for an apology?  Your boss say's were considering firing you, and you want the OP to ask for an apology?  This seems more likely to actually get you fired **faster**.

Comment: @MisterSortofPositive If the boss really wants to fire you, then yes (but then you are done for anyway). Otherwise he will be forced into a healthier situation. -- This assumes that the boss in question is more a project manager than a CEO.

Comment: You line of thought makes many, many, many assumptions.....

Comment: @MisterSortofPositive Indeed, but so do the other answers. I was mostly triggered by this bit "a task goes over the estimated time and I am being threatened with being let go" -- A situation I have been in several times as a PM got caught up in the heat of the moment, and best survived by NOT giving in and letting the aggressor 'smell blood'.

Comment: In a perfect world where all coworkers and bosses are logical, sensible and reasonable people, this would work. In the real world, the OP's boss has demonstrated they are not reasonable by throwing around 'interview fraud' after 2 years of employment. If you're in an environment where it's considered OK to threaten someone just because a task is going over its estimate, it's time to find a new environment.

Comment: @Cronax The whole point is that this is about manouvering towards a situation where the organization judges that it is NOT ok to throw around these kind of things. -- If you do nothing you will end up under the buss, only by acting you may be able to change the flow (the person who made the accusation may or may not turn around, but hopefully the rest of the organization is reasonable and will give you the needed support).

Comment: I kind of like this suggestion. They are trying to bully OP into either being a scapegoat or working harder. By demanding an apology, OP indicates that s/he won't put up with the bullying. Or, if the threat was made by an individual in the heat of the moment, asking for an apology just might snap him or her out of it.

Comment: If you're going to use this strategy, update your resume first.

Answer (score -2):

You don't give too much detail, including what the alleged fraud was about, but you could be a victim of bullying -

Assuming you are really not guilty of "interview fraud" : 
In my employee handbook (and I'm sure it would be similar in others, though this could be culture based also), some signs of bullying are

- unduly punishing or being over-critical about minor things
- intimidation / threats
- "instantaneous rage", often over trivial issues (you don't mention this but it may be applicable)
- deliberately setting unrealistic objectives so the victim can be criticised for failing to achieve them (again you don't say whether the deadline you missed was unrealistic)
- "this list is not exhaustive" (I'm sure a manager looking for excuses for disciplinary action and making false accusations could well be included though)

As houbie said, they might just be looking for an excuse to get rid of you, but you should find out your company's bullying policy, as well as the legal position in your location, and if your company has a HR person/dept, you could take it to them.

Comment: If there is not enough detail ask for it in comments.

Comment: @Brandin - Given the OP didn't say, "I committed interview fraud and I want to know how to get out of it" it's safe to assume the accusation is false. The rest is just there for information. It would be cumbersome to add a lengthy thread of comments for each point when the information would be useful in its own right to both the OP and other people similar situations.